# CPP infinit while-loop error when reading in struct data?

Tags: c++, struct, while-loop

I would like to use an infinite loop to read in Person struct (name, age, salary). I would like to break the loop when the user enters name as 'x'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Person
{
    char name[50];
    int age;
    float salary;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Person p1;
    vector <Person> p1_vec;
    while (true) {
        cout << "Enter Full name or simply 'x' to exit: ";
        cin.get(p1.name, 50);
        bool next_entry = strcmp(p1.name,"x");
        if (!next_entry) {
            break;
        }
        cout << "Enter age: ";
        cin >> p1.age;
        cout << "Enter salary: ";
        cin >> p1.salary;
        p1_vec.push_back(p1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly go throw Q/A guide to know how to ask question.

Comment: So what does _actually_ happen? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ignore the new line character that you get after reading a `salary` input:

```
cin >> p1.salary;
```

doing:

```
 cin >> p1.salary;
 cin.ignore(1, '\n');
```

will make the code to stop here:

```
cin.get(p1.name, 50);
```

and wait for another user input!

Answer (score 0):

`cin` state needs to be cleared after reading, try something like:

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

For example (depending on the amount of error tolerance you want)

```
while (true) 
{
    cout << "Enter Full name or simply 'x' to exit: ";
    cin.get(p1.name, 50);
    cin.clear();
    auto equal = strcmp(p1.name, "x")==0;
    if (equal)
    {
        break;
    }
    cout << "Enter age: ";
    cin >> p1.age;
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Enter salary: ";
    cin >> p1.salary;
    p1_vec.push_back(p1);
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cin.get(p1.name, 50)` does not consume the `\n`, that remains in the input buffer after having entered a salary; so it skips the input and leaves the values blank.

Write `cin >> p1.name` and it should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

After getting data from input buffer, you should clear it.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Person p1;
    vector <Person> p1_vec;
    while (true) {
        cout << "Enter Full name or simply 'x' to exit: ";
        cin.get(p1.name, 50);
        bool next_entry = strcmp(p1.name,"x");
        if (!next_entry) {
            break;
        }
        cout << "Enter age: ";
        cin >> p1.age;
        cout << "Enter salary: ";
        cin >> p1.salary;
        p1_vec.push_back(p1);
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
    }
}
```